# find dir xargs rm output to a file.log

Tags: find, xargs

I have a bash script, in the end will find folders with modified timestamps greater than 5 days then pipe it to xargs to rm. This is working fine and to print the command I am using -t option for the xargs as well. But I need this output written to a log file.
so my command line is as follows :

```
find /tmp/test -type d -mtime +5 -print0 | xargs -t -0 -I {} /bin/rm -rf '{}'
```

I would like to get the output to know which all folders are deleted to a file named  **rmdirs.log**

I tried redirecting it to a file but like below and it wont work;

```
find /tmp/test -type d -mtime +5 -print0 | xargs -t -0 -I {} /bin/rm -rf '{}' >> rmdirs.log
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try this: `find /tmp/test -type d -mtime +5 -exec /bin/rm -rf {} \; -print0 >> rmdirs.log` ... see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212957/find-multiple-execs-with-conditions

Comment: @Sundeep I am aware of the -exec rm but I dont want to use it; since while using "exec" it uses multiple times the CPU and ram than Xargs; For removing small files and folders thats ok ; I am using it in DB server with large gigs of folders need to be deleted; so exec is not a good option; so Y I was asking for help using XARGS;

Comment: @SAGARBHOOSHAN Did the comments or my answer solve your issue? If the answer helped, you can say thanks by up voting and/or checking as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I created a test environment with touch. This properly deletes the directory and logs the ones deleted to rmdirs.log file.

```
touch -t 202201010000 tmp/test/old
touch                 tmp/test/new

find tmp/test -type d -mtime +5 -print | \
    tee -a rmdirs.log | \
    tr '\12' '\0' | \
    xargs -0 -I {} /bin/rm -rf {}
```

- Use `tee`to append (-a) to the rmdirs.log file.
- Use `tr` to convert the newlines (\12) to null (\0) for safety.
- Finally run `xargs` to remove the files.